# Thorlabs Kinesis killing Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter

I am trying to use a Python script in a Jupyter notebook to control a Thorlabs Kinesis Position Aligner. My colleague wrote the script and it works fine on their computer, but when I run it, the kernel dies and throws the error "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

The part of the code in question is shown below. (It is sufficient to test problem if Kinesis is installed.) It requires having Thorlabs Kinesis software installed, which I do, and have checked that Kinesis runs the device properly. As far as I can tell all of the packages and permissions are the same on my computer as on my colleague's.

```
import clr #pip install pythonnet for this.
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

from System import String
from System import Decimal
from System.Collections import *

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Thorlabs\Kinesis") #double checked that this is correct location

# add .net reference and import so python can see .net
clr.AddReference("Thorlabs.MotionControl.Controls")
import Thorlabs.MotionControl.Controls   #this line kills the kernel

clr.AddReference("Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI")
clr.AddReference("Thorlabs.MotionControl.GenericPiezoCLI")
clr.AddReference("Thorlabs.MotionControl.KCube.PositionAlignerCLI")
clr.AddReference("Thorlabs.MotionControl.KCube.PiezoCLI")

from Thorlabs.MotionControl.DeviceManagerCLI import *  #these three imports work fine
from Thorlabs.MotionControl.GenericPiezoCLI import *
from Thorlabs.MotionControl.KCube.PositionAlignerCLI import *
```

The line `import Thorlabs.MotionControl.Controls` seems to be the one killing the kernel. The other imports below it seem to work fine.

I have tried:

- Updating numpy,
- Updating Anaconda,
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda as both local user and admin.

Help and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the error message you included complete? Please post the full error stacktrace.

Comment: @bad_coder  I've been unable to get Jupyter to give me any further error information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar error, check your path variable and make sure what you are appending is in the same format as the rest.  I had this problem when I accidentally tried to run a `.ipnyb` I had working on Windows Anaconda in a notebook server launched from WSL Ubuntu.  The path formats are different, and the kernal died each time I tried to access something through the path variable, with no further error message.

Also try double slashes in the `path.append()`  I used:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files\\Thorlabs\\Kinesis')
```